# Como setar o tamanho de botões de layout na versão 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

Por exemplo se eu tiver um um LinearLayout que ocupe todo o espaço na horizontal, se eu tiver dois botões, pra cada um ocupar metade da tela, como faço? GridLayout não funciona na 2.2 né?

Comment: Se você colocar dois botões dentro do LinearLayout ele não distribui igualmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `android:layout_weight` para definir proporcionalmente o espaço que ocupa cada botão.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BT1"
    <Button 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BT2"
</LinearLayout>
```

Como `layout_weight`, em ambos os casos, é definido com o valor 1, os dois botões terão o mesmo comprimento.
Por exemplo se o primeiro fosse definido com o valor 2 e o segundo com o valor 1, o primeiro botão teria o dobro do comprimento do segundo.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` para um e `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` para outro,definindo o `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` para os dois

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser preencher o tamanho do botão na horizontal, basta deixar a configuração padrão do Linear Layout.
Se quiser colocar um botão ao lado do outro pode usar dois tipos diferentes de layout: Table ou Relative. No caso do Table, você irá criar uma coluna para cada botão. No caso do Relative, você irá alinhar um botão de acordo com o outro (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).